# Number decomposition in Prolog

Tags: prolog, decomposition

I'm new to Prolog and I have the following question: How can I decompose a natural number N into a list, containing consecutive natural numbers whose sum is equal to N?

For example:

```
N=10, R=[1,2,3,4];

N=80, R=[14, 15, 16, 17, 18];

N=99, R=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

      R=[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

      R=[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

      R=[32, 33, 34]

      R=[49, 50]
```

EDIT:
I have tried to build the lists without using default methods and so far I managed to write this piece:

```
cand([H|_],H).
cand([_|T],E):-
    cand(T,E).

suma([],0).
suma([H|T],S):-
    suma(T,Temp),
    S is Temp+H.

list(0,[]).
list(N,[Nr|R]):-
    Nr is N-1,
    list(Nr,R).

generate(_,_,A,_,A).
generate(N,L,[H|T],S,R):-
    S<N,
    cand(L,E),
    not(cand([H|T],E)),
    E=:=H-1,
    suma([H|T],S),
    generate(N,L,[E,H|T],S,R).
start(N,Rez):-
    list(N,L),
    cand(L,E1),
    cand(L,E2),
    E2=:=E1-1,
    generate(N,L,[E2,E1],0,Rez).
```

But for some reason, no matter the number I input, the result is always the empty list.

Comment: Don't expect SO members to do your homework... We're only here to help *you* in doing it. So, please, tell us what you tried.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, for us to help you.

Comment: Do some research on the CLPFD library. It's the cleanest approach to this kind of problem. Google it and read up. Try some things, and come back with a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: How about using @mat's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) **constraints** to see that there are more solutions than you show:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

n_list(N, Ls) :-
    L #=< N,
    L #> 0,
    indomain(L),
    length(Ls, L),
    Ls ins 0..N,
    foldl(consecutive, Ls, _, _),
    sum(Ls, #=, N),
    label(Ls).

consecutive(A, Prev, A) :- A #= Prev + 1.
```

Example:

```
?- n_list(10, Ls).
Ls = [10] ;
Ls = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Ls = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] ;
false.
```

Another example:

```
?- n_list(80, Ls).
Ls = [80] ;
Ls = [14, 15, 16, 17, 18] ;
false.
```

I leave making this faster as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

This follows up on [@mat's previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874098/4609915).
Want mo' speed? Use redundant constraints like this!

```
n_list(N, Ls) :-
    L #=< N,
    L #>  0,
    L0 #= L-1,
    N0 #= (L0*L0+L0)//2,
    N  #= N0+K*L,
    K #>= 0,
    indomain(L),
    length(Ls, L),
    Ls ins 0..N,
    foldl(consecutive, Ls, _, _),
    sum(Ls, #=, N),
    label(Ls).
```

Runtime without redundant constraints:

```
?- time((N in 1..100,indomain(N),n_list(N,_),false)).
% 1,048,270,907 inferences, 85.594 CPU in 85.552 seconds (100% CPU, 12247032 Lips)
false.
```

Runtime with redundant constraints:

```
?- time((N in 1..100,indomain(N),n_list(N,_),false)).
% 10,312,514 inferences, 0.834 CPU in 0.833 seconds (100% CPU, 12369051 Lips)
false.
```